# ArrayList will not populate within a for loop while reading a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I'm attempting to write a program to see which numbers have shown the best results for each ball of the Mega Millions (just for fun, I understand it doesn't help you predict anything for the future).

THE PROBLEM:

The ArrayLists will not populate from the input from the BufferedReader, but I can print anything to the console, just not add it to an Array or ArrayList.

I apologize for how sloppy this is and all the weird namings:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MathStats mathStats = new MathStats();
    getFileInfo(); //Same class as main.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(mathStats.num1.size());
    //num1 should be populated after calling getFileInfo();

} //End of main


    private static void getFileInfo() {
    File listOfTickets = new File(**FILE**);
    MathStats mathStats = new MathStats();

    try {
        BufferedReader getInfo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                listOfTickets));

        String ticketInfo = getInfo.readLine();

        for (int i = 0; ticketInfo != null; i++) {

            ticketInfo.split("\n");

            System.out.println(ticketInfo);

            int a = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(25,
                    27));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(28,
                    30));
            int c = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(31,
                    33));
            int d = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(34,
                    36));
            int e = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(37,
                    39));
            int f = Integer.parseInt(ticketInfo.substring(40,
                    42));

            mathStats.setArrayValues(a, b, c, d, e, f);
            mathStats.setCount(i);

            ticketInfo = getInfo.readLine();
        }

        getInfo.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file");
        System.exit(0);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An I/O Error Occured");
        System.exit(0);

    }


}
```

The method *setArrayValues* just adds each respective int to its ArrayList or atleast its suppose to. It uses the normal list.add(a); to add each int.

Problem, when testing the size of each ArrayList in main (after calling this method) it returns 0 every time.

Here's some data to put into a text file if you'd like to test it (delete the extra lines in between)

11/04/2014  Mega Millions   09-15-24-39-41[01], Megaplier® : X4

10/31/2014  Mega Millions   11-29-36-58-67[15], Megaplier® : X2

10/28/2014  Mega Millions   03-50-57-58-60[11], Megaplier® : X5

10/24/2014  Mega Millions   02-14-21-28-55[03], Megaplier® : X3

10/21/2014  Mega Millions   05-35-37-41-66[11], Megaplier® : X5

10/17/2014  Mega Millions   21-31-43-56-60[12], Megaplier® : X4

Here is *setArrayValues*

```
    public void setArrayValues(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
    num1.add(a);
    num2.add(b);
    num3.add(c);
    num4.add(d);
    num5.add(e);
    num6.add(f);

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `setArrayValues`?

Comment: your catch blocks are not doing anything with the exception. try to add a print stack trace at least.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I don't see why... "can't find file" is pretty self-explanatory, we usually don't need to see what line it's occurring on.

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the `MathStats` class, but you're hiding it from us.

Comment: Can't find file is, but if you take the data I provided, throw it in a text file and use the path of the text file where I put FILE then it will be able to read the file.

Comment: _"when testing the size of each ArrayList in main (after calling this method) it returns 0"_ : but you instantiate the MathStats class here in this method. how can you refer to it in main?

Comment: @guido, i'm not sure if this answers your question, but in main I'm just calling this method (*getFileInfo*)

Comment: the MathStats object you create will only be local in getFileInfo. when you get back to main you don't see it. pls show your main

Comment: @guido, so if I try to populate an ArrayList through that local MathStats object will that ArrayList still be accessible in main?

Comment: Only if it is static ( and it seems static from your main code ). Show the MathStats code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guido said, you're instantiating a new MathStats in the getFileInfo method, so the one instatiated in main won't be populated. You can fix this by passing a reference to the one created in main to the getFileInfo method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MathStats mathStats = new MathStats();
    getFileInfo(mathStats); //Same class as main.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(mathStats.num1.size());
    //num1 should be populated after calling getFileInfo();

} //End of main


private static void getFileInfo(MathStats mathStats) {
    File listOfTickets = new File(**FILE**);
    try {
      //..
```